# Can't change runtime version of produced DLL in ASP.NET Core Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5, asp.net5

I am building a .NET 5 based ASP.NET Web Application for REST APIs. It is a POC at the moment. My hosting provider only supports `5.0.2` runtime but the SDK version came with VS2019 installed `.NET 5.0.103 (runtime 5.0.3)`. I need to produce DLL with target runtime `5.0.2`.

In order to be able to produce DLL for runtime `5.0.2`, I installed `.NET SDK version 5.0.102`. Now I have both SDK and runtime.

Now, I have SDKs and Runtimes as below (`dotnet --info`)

```
.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
```

I tried to force use earlier version using `global.json` file. I put the file in the folder where `csproj` file exists. The content is as below:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "5.0.102"
  }
}
```

`dotnet --version` and `dotnet --info` also reports the SDK in use is `5.0.102` if run these commands from the project directory.

```
D:\Projects-DriveD\VS\AspNetCoreWebSample\AspNetCoreWebSample>dotnet --version
5.0.102

D:\Projects-DriveD\VS\AspNetCoreWebSample\AspNetCoreWebSample>dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.102
 Commit:    71365b4d42

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19042
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.102\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.3  <==========================================
  Commit:  c636bbdc8a

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
```

But even that, the DLL produced is targeting runtime version `5.0.3`. I think the problem could be because of Host Version is still `5.0.3` but I am not entirely sure.

I am verifying the runtime version of produced DLL using the `Jetbrains dotpeek` tool.
[image]

How can I force Visual Studio to produce `DLL` which targets runtime version `5.0.2` instead of `5.0.3` runtime?

Comment: From the doc [Select the .NET version to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection), you can try add `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>5.0.2</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>` in csproj.

Comment: @Vernou Your solution worked. I had gone through that page multiple times but somehow missed that part. I was tackling this problem for the past 24 hours with no luck. Thank you so much! You can maybe write an answer to the same.

Comment: This information is in the part "Self-contained deployments", not obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official documentation [Select the .NET version to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection) :

> The RuntimeFrameworkVersion element overrides the default version policy. For self-contained deployments, the RuntimeFrameworkVersion specifies the exact runtime framework version. For framework-dependent applications, the RuntimeFrameworkVersion specifies the minimum required runtime framework version.

In your csproj, you can add :

```xml
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>5.0.2</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
```